# Pug Image Link Won't Render

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug, jade4j

I am trying to render an image in pug that is hosted elsewhere on the web, not as a static asset in my project.  I can navigate to it fine and pull it up in my browser, but when I load my webpage it gives me the error in the console

```
Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
```

I am trying to render the image as:

```
img.picture(src='https://somedomain.com/picture' alt='Some Picture')
```

Comment: Have you tried running the page as static HTML?  This doesn't look like a Pug error to me

Comment: Just configure `helmet.contentSecurityPolicy(options)` in the [Helmet](https://helmetjs.github.io/#reference) - add `https://somedomain.com` into `img-src` directive.